# Azure Logic App - Access SQL Server running in Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

My client has a SQL Server instance installed on an Azure VM.

I am building an Azure Logic App and the end result is to write to this SQL Server instance.

To connect to this SQL Server instance running on the Azure VM do I need to treat it the same way I would as an on-prem SQL Server and install the gateway softwaare, or is there a better way since the VM is in Azure?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the down vote. If this is a basic question then please point me to some relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use a gateway. A gateway is mainly used for securing the data connection from a cloud service to an on-prem datbase, since the traffic goes over the public internet.

With the DB on an Azure VM, you can deploy your logic app into an integrated service environment. This keeps the traffic between logic app and DB on the private VNET. See the documentation on ISEs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/connect-virtual-network-vnet-isolated-environment-overview).